# Trouble deriving the value of $⟨x_i|x_i⟩$ in an infinite dimensional vector space as the Dirac Delta $δ(x_i- x_i)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, quantum-mechanics

On pg. 57 of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, the author considers a vector space of "infinite dimensional vectors", conceived of as a vector space of functions defined on some closed interval.  The inner product $⟨f,g⟩$ is defined as

$$
⟨f|g⟩ = ∫_a^b f^*(x)g(x)dx
$$

while a basis $|x_i⟩$ is defined as a function $x_i(x)$ s.t. $x_i(x) = 0$ everywhere except for $x_i(x_i) = 1$ (the author doesn't actually explicitly state this, but this I'm assuming is what he means?).  At this point, it seems to me that

$$
⟨x_i|x_i⟩ = ∫_a^b x_i^*(x)x_i(x)dx = 0
$$

since the integral of any function 0 almost everywhere is 0. But instead the author goes on to derive that the value is actually $δ(x_i-x_i) = ∞$:

> [image]

This seems to me to be highly problematic since since an inner product is supposed to be a scalar function which returns scalar values, and $∞ ∉ \mathbb{C}$ is not scalar. In fact even the notion of $⟨x_i|f⟩$ seems to me to be confused, since

$$
⟨x_i|f⟩ = ∫_a^b x_i^*(x)f(x)dx = 0
$$

since again the integral of a function 0 everywhere except for $x^*_i(x_i)f(x_i) = 1*f(x_i) = f(x_i)$ is still just $0$. Yet the author wants to say that this integral evalutes to $f(x_i)$?

Comment: If you want an actual rigorous treatment of this, you'll want to look up operator-valued measures which are related to the spectral theorem. This is all a statement about the spectral theory of the position operator $x$. The way this is treated in physics is "cute" but woefully misleading and bad math. It's not inherently wrong (at least at the end results aren't), but for someone mathematically inclined, it definitely "feels" wrong.

Comment: "s.t. $x_i(x) = 0$ everywhere except for $x_i(x_i) = 1$" It's more like $x_i(x_i) = \infty$, exactly infinitely enough that $\int x_i \, dx = 1$ (which doesn't make rigorous sense).

Comment: @Arthur That makes much more sense though (informally)!

Answer (score 1):

Further to @CosmasZachos's answer, nothing in the excerpt says $x_i(x_i)=1$, i.e. that $x_i(x)=\delta_{x,\,x_i}$ is a Kronecker delta. This is a misconception on your part. It really should be a Dirac delta, so$$\langle x_i|x_j\rangle=\int_a^b\delta(x-x_i)\delta(x-x_j)dx=\delta(x_i-x_j)$$ provided $x_i\in(a,\,b)$ (otherwise the RHS is $0$ instead).

Comment: I think you actually read the OP's  "a basis |⟩  is defined as a function" correctly. I had no clue he actually meant "a basis defined  through  the wavefunctions  ...", i.e. $|x_i\rangle\equiv \int\!\!dx    ~~x_i(x) |x\rangle =\int\!\!dx    ~ \delta(x_i-x) |x\rangle$ in proper Dirac notation...

Comment: @CosmasZachos viz. $x_i(x):=\langle x|x_i\rangle$ so $\int dxx_i(x)|x\rangle=\int dx|x\rangle\langle x|x_i\rangle=|x_i\rangle$ by identity insertion.

Comment: Sure, I wrote it directly as per the definition of wavefunctions as the coefficients of  kets in the canonical Dirac coordinate basis...